# Printing Scale Is at %100 however It really prints at %15

Tags: printing

High I have Ubuntu 14.04 
and when Printing in chrome and in the ubuntu system pdf viewer the page has been scaled way to small. and I can't change it

However firefox has printed in the correct scale.

I have a HP OfficeJet 4635

The Scale Option is at %100 in the dialog. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the scale in Chrome? The scale doesn't seem to display in my Chrome, so you probably should use the System print dialog instead (Shift+Ctrl+P). Also make sure the Margins, Page Size and Orientation are the same. For the PDF Viewer, try to use other viewer (maybe [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) or [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/)?.

P/S: It's more like a workaround than a fix.